# JusPayExpress Checkout error - JSURLNotPassed (102)

Tags: ios, swift

I am facing a strange issue in JusPayExpressCheckout SDK.

My end url is in the form of - "https://dev.merchant.com/payments/app-success"

I have two options for payment ->

**1. Card Payment:**
I perform the initialization of environment as:

```
checkout.environment(SANDBOX, merchantId: AppConstants.PaymentString.merchantId, orderId: model.orderId, cardNumber: model.cardNumber, cardExpiryYear: model.cardExpiryYear, cardExpiryMonth: model.cardExpiryMonth, cardSecurityCode: model.cardSecurityCode, nameOnCard: model.nameOnCard, authType: DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION, saveToLocker: true, endUrlRegexes: [ "https:\\/\\/dev\\.merchant\\.com\\/payments\\/app-success.*$"])
```

***This Works***

**2. NetBankingPayment**

I perform the initialization of environment as:

```
checkout.environment(SANDBOX, merchantId: AppConstants.PaymentString.merchantId, orderId: model.orderId, netbankingBank: model.bankId, endUrlRegexes: [ "https:\\/\\/merchant\\.acko\\.com\\/payments\\/app-success.*$"])
```

**Strange... This fails by throwing:
"error - The operation couldn’t be completed. (JuspayError error 102.)"**

Even though the regex is same in both the cases.

Can someone please let me know that what is going wrong and if this is a case of wrong endUrlRegex, what is the correct regex for the endURL?

Answer (score 0):

It will always work if the endURL specified while creating the order and the regex specified in the app are matching.

In your case, please check the JusPay sandbox dashboard and verify whether the selected net-banking option is configured properly. 102 error code is returned when payment URL is empty or if a suitable gateway to process the payment is not found.